# how do i make a stick the runs /Tick freeze

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to create a Za Warudo stick but I have searched on the internet for answers and found none.

Can someone help?

Comment: Hi Andreas, can you please be more specific? What exactly is a Za Waradu stick, what do you want it to do exactly? I assume it's a weapon that freezes entities you hit with it, but could you just spell that out?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Just a suggestion, you should also clear up the title, as it's very ambiguous what you're talking about (extremely confusing). You may also want to mention what results you found that may be close to your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please see our [guide on asking Minecraft commands questions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797), especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far”. Then, [edit] your post and add the requested information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently impossible to run commands from an item such as a stick (as far as I know). Your best bet would to use a [Carrot/Warped Fungus on a Stick](https://zedwork.co.uk/wiki/Using_carrot_on_a_sticks_as_triggers).